# How to don't give full path in logstash

Tags: logstash

I want to ask in logstash
The below is my path in file plugin.

```
path => "/home/username/logstash/logs/inputs/.."
```

My configurations at

```
"/home/username/logstash/usage/confs/.."
```

When I change the home

> /home/username/logstash

with

> /../../

I get an error.
I want to ask how can i give path from context root in logstash ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file input does not support relative paths. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-path) says "Paths must be absolute and cannot be relative". It [tests](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/blob/bf4b8e573729000e97e4ccffbf8d792eef011d73/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb#L282) this using the ruby [Pathname::relative?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-relative-3F) function.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Your answer is correct. Thanks for answering. If you like the question feel free to upvote :)